`systemd-networkd` is not managing interface even though configuration file exists
I have udev rule to prevent interface getting a weird name:
# /etc/udev/rules.d/eth0.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:00:de:ad:be:ef", NAME="eth0"

Also a network config file:
# /etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

And yet when my system boots, eth0 is down. I can bring it up with ip link set eth0 up but then networkctl says the interface is unmanaged:
IDX LINK TYPE    OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo   looback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0 ether   carrier     unmanaged

So my big problems here are

Interface not coming up on boot
Interface not managed by systemd-networkd

I can't find any extensive documentation, mostly just forum posts for related problems. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.
EDIT
Just tried with PermanentMACAdress=00:00:de:ad:be:ef instead of Name=eth0 and then systemctl restart systemd-networkd. Still getting "unmanaged".
However then I ran dhclient and now at least there's an IP address for the link, and it's now routable:
IDX LINK TYPE    OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo   looback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0 ether   routable    unmanaged


Oh, yes that's a typo. Can't copy/paste so I had to type it.

What distro? Maybe there's something else interfering

Because it may be distro-specific, I've posted this to https://forum.manjaro.org/t/systemd-networkd-reports-device-as-unmanaged/167912
